# Why does copying partitioned tables in BigQuery take longer than non-partitioned tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

We've started migrating to using partitioned tables in BigQuery. We've noticed that copying a partitioned table takes considerably longer than a non-partitioned table - in every case. I'm sure there is a very good reason for this e.g. because of the underlying architecture of BigQuery & partitioned tables.

For example (copying in same project & to the same dataset):

> **Non-partitioned table:**
>
> - **Size**: 15GB, 87M rows
> - **Copy time**: 3 seconds
> - **Job id**: bquijob_64e11150_15b373c714a
>
> **Partitioned table:**
>
> - **Size**: 15GB, 87M rows (same table as above, but partitioned)
> - **Copy time**: 16 minutes
> - **Job id**: bquijob_6bae14c3_15b373e623d

---

Is there a trick/workaround to speed up copying partitioned tables in BigQuery?

Comment: just wondering: how many partitions does the table have (mental math, don't take it seriously: 365*3 seconds ~= 16 minutes)

Comment: 622 partitions contained

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I would expected to be in parallel copy, not ending up with linear time.

Comment: That's why I asked to not take my math seriously, but the answer to the question still was an interesting data point to have

Comment: @FelipeHoffa - so, is BQ performing 622 sequential load jobs under the hood?

Comment: *copy, not "load" (can't edit!)

Comment: I asked to not take my mental exercise seriously for that exact reason. I didn't say that, and I was asking to not be taken as saying that.

Comment: Roger that @FelipeHoffa!

Comment: now, if you want to do some O(n) experiments, that would be interesting data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been told through our enterprise support channel that it's working as designed and there's nothing that can be done to speed up the copy on partitioned tables (paraphrasing).

I've raised a feature request in an attempt to get this changed, but I doubt it's going to be a top priority!

Anyway, in the interest of posterity, here's the FR if anyone wants to track it.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37012156